# nodejs why is my code returning [object Object] instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, promise

so I am building a website and using nodejs to do a bunch of api calls and populate all the info. I have a homepage which has a sidebar where people can sort by 'categories'. but when I run my code instead of the categories being displayed in the html I get `[object Object]`. I have tried a whole bunch of things but still it only returns `[object Object]`. here's the code:

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = new express.Router();
const categoriesFunction = require('../controllers/categories')
// get index page
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    let requestString = '/apps'
    allApps = await openChannelRequest(requestString, req, res)

    await res.render('index', {
    categories: categoriesFunction,
  // this is where I try to add the categories to the homepage
})
})
```

here's the controller where I'm grabbing all categories data and storing it. I'm pretty sure I can do this in the index.js page but a few weeks ago when I started this I made controllers for some reason. if that is not the best way to do this please let me know.

categories.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var request = require('request');
var categoricalNames = []
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'a working url',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'working authorization'
  },
  'contentType': 'application/json'
};

var categoriesFunction = async() => request(options, function (error, response) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  console.log('inside categories function')
  var categoryName = ''

  if(error || !response)
     {
        // report error
        reject(new Error('Try Again'));
     }
     else
     {
        //process response
        var body = JSON.parse(response.body); 
        var jsonResponse = body.values
        jsonResponse.forEach(function(obj) {
           // console.log(obj.label)
            categoryName = obj.label
           // JSON.stringify(categoryName)
            categoricalNames.push(categoryName)
        });
        categoricalNames.push({categoryName});
      //  console.log(categoricalNames)
        // report success
        JSON.stringify(categoricalNames)
        resolve(categoricalNames);
     }
})

});

module.exports.getPlaceDetails = categoriesFunction;
```

for awhile I thought my code wasn't working but console.logs in my `categoriesFunction` function reveal that the array is populating correctly. it's just not being pushed to the index correctly. and trying that method on the index.js page does not do anything for me. still just get `[object Object]`. not really sure why. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get when you use an object where a string is expected.

Comment: @Barmar so how do I get it to return not that? specifically an array

Comment: May you figure out where it becomes `[object Object]`? What is `response.body`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I do not know where it is becoming `[object Object]`. when the function finishes I can output an array to the console so I'm not sure where it's happening. `response.body` is a big json object

Comment: May you use console logs or dev tools to find out where is becomes `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. basically needed to write a cleaner Promise and make sure not to return the array but to *resolve* the array. and also there needed to be a variable in index.js that `awaits` the results of `categoriesFunction()`

here's what index.js looks like now

```
const express = require('express')
const router = new express.Router();
const categoriesFunction = require('../controllers/categories')
// get index page
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    let requestString = '/apps'
    allApps = await openChannelRequest(requestString, req, res)

    const thing = await categoriesFunction()
    // this is important cause the method needs to be called before its inserted
    await res.render('index', {
        categories: thing,
  // this is where I try to add the categories to the homepage
})
})
```

and here's what the categories.js file looks like

```
let categoriesFunction = function() {
return new Promise(resolve => 
request(options,
  (error, response) => {
    var categoryName = ''
    var body = JSON.parse(response.body); 
    var jsonResponse = body.values
    jsonResponse.forEach(function(obj) {
        categoryName = obj.label
        JSON.stringify(categoryName)
        categoricalNames.push(categoryName)
    });
    console.log(categoricalNames)
    resolve(categoricalNames)
   // now that this is resolved it can be returned 
  }
  ))
}
```